# Using an opamp, I want to double a DC input signal that varies from 230 mVDC to 2300 mVDC. I want to use a single supply voltage of +5 vDC

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image: schematic]

Source: [Circuit Digest - Practical Example of Non-inverting Amplifier](https://circuitdigest.com/tutorial/non-inverting-operational-amplifier)

I want an opamp to double an input signal that varies from 230 mVDC to 2300 mVDC.  That is, with 230 mVDC in, I want an output voltage of 460 mVDC and with an input voltage of 2300 mVDC I want an output voltage 4600 mVDC.  I want to use a single supply voltage of +5 vDC to power the opamp.  The attached image is what I have found so far except the feedback resistor should equal the input resistor for a gain of 2 instead a gain of 3 as drawn.  What I am most confused about is the actual values of Rf and Rin.  The source voltage will be a low impedance DC voltage and the output will be driving the A/D input of a uP.

Comment: 1. There is no "Rin" in the drawing. Do you mean R1?
2. What's confusing about it? --- the labeled value of 1.2 kohms should work well.

Comment: gooberpat - Hi, Please note the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, for online material the source webpage or PDF etc. should be named & linked (see that rule regarding references for books / articles etc.). In order to help you, I found what I believe to be the source webpage link for the copied image & added it. For the future, please remember it's your responsibility to do that :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Part of your confusion could be calling the resistors Rin and Rf. That suggests to me that you've also been looking at a different configuration, an inverting amplifier, which often calls the resistors that.

Your diagram shows a non-inverting amplifier, with resistors labelled R1 and R2. Stick with those.

For a gain of 2, you need equal value resistors. You could stick with both as 2.4 k, but that's a bit low, it requires a relatively large current through the resistors which loads the amplifier excessively. A pair of 10 k or even 100 k resistors should be OK.

If you want 4.6 V out, with a 5 V rail, then you need a rail-to-rail, or R2R, amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit you have shown is an op-amp non-inverting amplifier whose gain is

$$
A_V=\frac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}}=\Big(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\Big)
$$

So, to have a gain of 2 (doubling the input) the resistors should be equal.

> with an input voltage of 2300 mVDC I want an output voltage 4600 mVDC. I want to use a single supply voltage of +5 vDC to power the opamp.

In theory this is possible but in practice this is limited by the op-amp itself. Few things worth to note here:

- Not all op-amps behave well with 5V supply.
- Not all op-amps' outputs can swing too close to the rails i.e. with 5V supply the maximum output you can get can be limited to 4.5V or even lower. Likewise, you may not get 0V when the input is zero because, again, the swing can be limited to 0.4V or higher.

So you need to select an op-amp that can work with 5V supply and has maximum swing available. Rail-to-rail op-amps could be the first thing to check.

> What I am most confused about is the actual values of Rf and Rin.

This depends on the application. Because these resistors are, practically, the load of the op-amp's output, they will draw current from the source constantly. If your application requires minimum consumption (e.g. battery-operated systems) then these resistors should be as high as possible. But in this case, you'll be limited by the op-amp's input bias currents. If this is not the case, then selecting a few to a few tens of kiloohms could be a good choice e.g. R<sub>1</sub> = R<sub>2</sub> = 1k ... 50k

Answer (score 0):

You need to pick an op-amp and then you can explore the range of resistor values R that will work well with that op-amp.

In this case you need the input common mode voltage to cover the range of 230mV to 2.3V with a power supply of (say) 4.5V or 4.75V minimum and 5.5V  or 5.25V maximum (to allow for some tolerance). That leaves only 100mV or 150mV headroom on the high end, which will probably be the limiting specification for most op-amps.

The op-amp output must swing from 460mV to 4.6V with loading of 2R to ground (in parallel with whatever loading the ADC input imposes). Depending on the type of ADC input there may be a loading that varies with the ADC reading rate. If there's a filter on the input there may be some loading from that. That leaves only 100mV or 150mV headroom on the high end for the output, which will probably be the limiting specification for most op-amps.

There are a number of op-amps which will not work (eg. LM358, TL071, LM741) because of those two constraints. Few, if any, high precision loop-amps such as AD8676 will work. There are some 'zero-drift' amplifiers which will work with high DC accuracy (mostly their advantage is low offset voltage), however noise may be an issue. For about the lowest cost and not many ADC bits, you might start by looking at [LMV321A](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmv321a.pdf) and [MCP6001](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MSLD/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP6001-1R-1U-2-4-1-MHz-Low-Power-Op-Amp-DS20001733L.pdf) (both CMOS). Or perhaps the [LMV321](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmv321.pdf) (bipolar).

From a loading perspective, R = 10kΩ and higher will probably be okay (depending on the op-amp). If you go too high (say more than 100kΩ) there are a couple of issues that can eventually crop up- errors due to bias current can become more important, the high impedance may allow noise or PCB leakage to affect the output significantly, and possibly the amplifier may overshoot or even oscillate due to phase shift from amplifier input capacitance. The LMV321 being bipolar has a relatively heavy maximum bias current of 500nA over temperature so using 100kΩ resistors could cause a 50mV error at the output, more than the 18mV that could arise from the 9mV maximum Vos. Typically, much better. They don't bother specifying (or testing) a maximum bias current for the CMOS parts, but the typical is in the tens of pA at room temperature. For something more accurate, there are parts such as [LTC2063](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc2063-2064-2065.pdf) which is better in most ways (noisy though, and maybe 10x cost).

TL;DR: Use 10kΩ to 100kΩ if your amplifier is a CMOS type. Perhaps a bit higher if you need low power consumption for long-term battery operation.